# Handling error responses from WCF JSONP

Tags: javascript, jquery, wcf, jsonp

I have a WCF service exposing a JSONP interface by setting the `CrossDomainScriptAccessEnabled` property on the binding. There is an example with code similar to mine [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/223572/Calling-Cross-Domain-WCF-service-using-Jquery-Java). When the server would normally return HTTP 200 it behaves as I expected and returns javascript like `jsonp_callback({"result":5})`. However when I throw an exception the format is something like:

```
jsonp_callback({"error_message":"needs auth"}, 401);
```

The problem there is that as far as I can tell jQuery always expects a single parameter in the JSONP callback. Is there any way I can access the second parameter with jQuery's JSONP handling? Is there another sensible framework that would make this easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do this with jQuery. But for my current purposes it worked fine implementing the JSONP myself:

```
var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
var cb = "jsonp_" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
window[cb] = function(result, statusCode) {
    try {
        onResult(result, statusCode);
    } finally { 
        delete window[cb];
    }
}
scriptTag.src = url + "?callback=" + cb + "&input=" + encodeURIComponent(data);
$('head').append(scriptTag);
```